# css setting height of elements percentaged

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm using jquery-mobile and I'd like to have the control-elements of my main-view to fill the entire available height and width, like in this picture:

[image]
To set the height like:

```
<div id="ButtonContent" style="height:100%>
   <button style="height:50%/>
   <button style="height:50%/>
</div>
```

doesnt work. See 
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marcelly/6xnuU/)

I also would like to have this div-container to fill the entire space:

[image]

Therefore I have this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marcelly/yvB8U/2/)

I tried to set the height of the div-conatiner and it's content to 100%, but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some concepts you have to understand:

1. The answer from Hiigaran.
2. Button are inline elements.

This could be what you want:

```
<div id="ButtonContent" style="height: 500px">
    <div style="height: 50%"><button style="height: 100%"/></div>
    <div style="height: 50%"><button style="height: 100%"/></div>
</div>
```

Try on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QK27v/)

Comment: So I could set the height of the body by myself to make the percantage configuration work? Would <script>document.body.style.height = window.innerHeight</script> work?

Comment: try it this way: `$("#ButtonContent").css("height",window.innerHeight+"px")`
updated:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QK27v/2/)

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding, you can't set `height:100%;` if you don't have an absolute value height on the parent element. For example, if you have the following HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="something"></div>
</body>
```

This CSS will not work:

```
.something{height:100%;}
```

But this one should:

```
body{height:500px;}
.something{height:100%;}
```

If you are tailing to mobile devices, continue using percentage as you normally would, but make sure that the body tag is set to the pixel height that the relevant device(s) have.

Answer (score 0):

Add following code in your css file.

```
 #boxBrowserContent .ui-btn{height:150px;margin:10px;}

 #boxBrowserContent{padding-top:100px;}

 .ui-grid-b .ui-block-a, .ui-grid-b .ui-block-b, .ui-grid-b .ui-block-c {
    height: 400px;
    width: 33.25%;
  }
```